# styled-component named imports throw error "Element type is invalid: expected a string ..." in unit test

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-testing-library

I am using styled-component with React. **If I put each styled-component in a separate file and use *default exports/imports* => no issue**. However, I want to put a group of styled-components in a single file with *named exports/imports* like this

```
// styles.css.js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledDiv1 = styled.div`
    border: solid 1px red;
`;

export const StyledDiv2 = styled.div`
    ...
`;

export const StyledButton = styled.button`
    ...
`;

....
```

and use it like this

```
// TestComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyledDiv1 } from './styles.css';

const TestComponent = () => <StyledDiv1>test</StyledDiv1>;

export default TestComponent;
```

This works no problem when run the application but failed when running unit test. For example, a unit test with react-testing-library like this

```
// TestComponent.test.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';

describe('<TestComponent> tests', () => {
    it('should render component', () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<TestComponent></TestComponent>);

        expect(getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });});
```

will throw this error when running the test

> ```
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> ```

```
Check the render method of `TestComponent`.

   6 |     it('should render component', () => {
   7 |         // Arrange
>  8 |         const { getByText } = render(<TestComponent></TestComponent>);
     |                               ^
   9 |
  10 |         expect(getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument();
  11 |     });

  at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26629:21)
  at createFiberFromElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26652:15)
  at reconcileSingleElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15526:23)
  at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15586:35)
  at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18089:28)
  at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18853:5)
  at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20162:16)
  at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:336:14)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
  at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
```

**Attempts:**

I tried the following:

- Upgrade *@testing-library/jest-dom* and *@testing-library/react* to latest.
- Update *styled-components* to latest.
- I try to create a test with enzyme and mount/shallow .

but got same error. Any help/explanation appreciate.

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the file `styles.css.js` to anything else, e.g., `components.js`? Or can you import as `import { StyledDiv1 } from './styles.css.js';` instead?

Answer (score 0):

this is supposed to be a js file not a css file

`import { StyledDiv1 } from './styles.css';`

you still use it the same way you are, styled components is css in js, so a .css file doesn't know what to do with it

edit:
I just noticed the file is named `styles.css.js`. that might be throwing something off because it might be looking for a .css file. try renaming it, or importing the entire thing with the .js at the end

Comment: Rename 'styles.css.js' to 'components.js'  does not fix it, got same error.

Comment: it also depends on the file location. if the style file is in the same directory as the component, which it looks like it is from the code, then you should be able to name the file anything you want as long as it ends with .js .... for instance `import { someStyle } from './anyNameYouWant.js';` My personal flavor is `import { someStyle } from './someComponentName.styles.js';` , where the actual name of the style file would be `someComponentName.styles.js`

Comment: sure but have you try to create a unit test for it , does it work ? My point is all these ways works when we run the application normally, but failed when run in the unit tests.